# Removing fraction of a dataset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am fairly new to python and numpy scipy packages in particular. 
I am doing regression analysis for a class assignment which involves trying different regression techniques on a data set and see which one works. This involves deleting values from a dataset and see which algorithm performs well with reduced data set. Right now I am indexing upto a fraction of the length of dataset. 
Something like.

```
data = np.loadtxt("filename")
to_be_used = data[0:int(0.6(len(data)))]
```

Is there any other way I can do this? Say, I want to randomly select 60% of the data instead of the first 60 elements.

Comment: You should probably create a new reduced array. Anyway, please show what you have tried. A short example of initial array and desired result would also be nice. Also, what's wrong with just fancy-indexing the full array?

Comment: There is some rule to reduce the array?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a random set of data from your array using the `numpy.random.choice` function:

```
subset = np.random.choice(data, int(len(data)*0.6), replace=False)
```

However, if you want to create multiple non-overlapping random sets, you should instead shuffle your array, then use regular slices to get the amount you want in each chunk. For instance, to randomly split your data in half:

```
np.shuffle(data)
one_random_half = data[:len(data)//2]
other_random_half = data[len(data)//2:]
```

Comment: Your first line of code is missing a `np.arange( ... )` around the first `len(data)`. Why create the intermediate `indexes` array? Why not use `np.random.choice` directly on `data`?

Comment: There's no need for the `arange` call, as `choice` will work as if you passed one anyway if you pass an integer value in place of an array-like object. You're right though that creating an array of indexes is silly when you can instead just use `choice` directly on the dataset. I'm not sure why I didn't just do that directly. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that about choice. Very convenient indeed!